# Are the sets of maximal ideals containing particular elements of a Boolean algebra closed under infinite unions?

Tags: general-topology, boolean-algebra

I was perusing [a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOqXx.jpg) for a project I am doing, and the set up is kind of a mouthful. But basically we have a boolean algebra $B$; for each $x$ in $B$, let $M_x$ be the set of maximal ideals of $B$ that don't contain $x$. And let $M$ be the set of all maximal ideals of $B$.

Now the book just remarks that $\{M_x \mid x\in B\}$ can be all the open sets of a topology on M. However, I don't quite see how it's closed under infinite union, since, well, $B$ isn't necessarily complete, right? Any pointers would be appreciated, as I am a little bit stumped.

(FYI, the screenshot is from Lattices and Ordered Algebraic Structures by TS Blyth.)

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, the statement in the book is wrong (though it appears from the following sentence that the author had the correct statement in mind and just wrote it wrong).  Except in trivial cases (when $B$ is finite), $\{M_x:x\in B\}$ will not be closed under infinite unions.  (Even when $B$ is complete it will not be closed under infinite unions, since the map $x\mapsto M_x$ does *not* turn infinite joins into infinite unions; that only works for finite joins.)  The correct topology to take is instead the topology *generated* by $\{M_x:x\in B\}$, so an open set is a union of sets of the form $M_x$ (since such sets are closed under finite intersections).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was thinking he might've meant the topology generated by it... That makes more sense.

Comment: @BipedalPlatypus The start of the proof are the facts he needs to check that the $M_x$ form a base for a topology, also mentioned in texts like Munkres, Engelking, end the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) page. The author then  correctly states that all open sets are *unions* of sets of the form $M_x$, just as expected. I expect the word base disappeared  between manuscript and final version...